# .NET ODATA - XML Serializer - Deserialize nested objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xml:base="xxx" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <id>xxx</id>
    <title>xxx</title>
    <updated>2018-02-12T11:33:38.737Z</updated>
    <link href="xxx" rel="self" title="xxx"></link>
    <entry>
        <id>xxx</id>
        <category term="xxx" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"></category>
        <title></title>
        <updated>2018-02-11T22:04:10.990Z</updated>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int64">123456789</d:ID>
                <d:AutoNumber m:type="Edm.Int64">313800</d:AutoNumber>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>xxx</id>
        <category term="xxx" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"></category>
        <title></title>
        <updated>2018-02-11T22:04:10.990Z</updated>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int64">987654321</d:ID>
                <d:AutoNumber m:type="Edm.Int64">313800</d:AutoNumber>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

I want to Deserialize this XML and store the data on SQL Server using the following models;

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "feed", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
public class Feed
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "updated")]
    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "entry")]
    public List<Entry> Entries { get; set; }

    public Feed()
    {
        Entries = new List<Entry>();
    }
}    

public class Entry
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID")]
    public long? ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AutoNumber")]
    public long? AutoNumber{ get; set; }
}
```

I use the following method;

```
public void LoadXml()
{

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Feed), "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("myfile.xml"))
    {
        Feed readFeed = serializer.Deserialize(sr) as Feed;
        foreach(var entry in readFeed.Entries)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(entry.ID);
            System.Console.WriteLine(entry.AutoNumber);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(readFeed.Updated);                
    }
}
```

The Feed class gets mapped correctly, the entry class is not mapped correctly as it sits inside the "content type" and "m:properties" tags. How can I map the  properties ID and AutoNumber to the Entry Class?